# Можно ли отправить любой файл по id aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, telebot, aiogram

Мне нужно отправить **любое вложение** *(фото,видео,аудио и тд)* **не** загружая файл с компьютера, а используя **file_id**.
Возможно ли это сделать? И если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, но для этого есть несколько замечаний, а именно:

1. Вы должны где-то хранить эти file_id
2. Вы должны знать тип файла, который стоит за этим file_id (фото, аудио, документ, etc.)
3. Если Вы знаете, что файл - фотография, и знаете его ID, то отправить можно очень просто:
   `await bot.send_photo(chat_id=123456, photo='file_id_abcd123')`

Насколько мне известно, бот может отправлять файлы, которые уже были загружены в него, т.е. Вы не сможете отправить файлы из чужого бота. Но насчёт этого пункта я не уверен, можете проверить сами.